# Why doesn't this MySQL query delete any rows?

Tags: mysql, join

On the face of it, my use-case is quite simple. I have two tables: `order` and `line`. `order` contains `id` and `datetime`, and `line` has a reference to `id` in the `order` table. Unfortunately this is a very old system and I cannot (i.e. not allowed to modify the system to) use foreign keys with update/delete triggers.

I was [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154707/mysql-delete-from-one-table-with-join) and wrote my own query to do a similar thing. Basically I want to delete all the `line`s associated with an `order` when the order is deleted, whenever that order is over two years old:

```
DELETE a
FROM 
  `line` AS a
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS b ON a.`order_id` = b.`id`
WHERE
  b.`datetime` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```

Currently nothing is happening - no rows are affected. Changing the query to just select, with the same join and where clause, returns a number of results fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try changing it to `DELETE a.* FROM...`

Comment: The `.*` should optional http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doc says `tbl_name`, not `table_references`. So this might work:

```
DELETE line
FROM 
  line
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS b ON line.`order_id` = b.`id`
WHERE
  b.`datetime` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to actually do it without the need for a subquery, and you explained exactly why mine wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

the DELETE command is used to delete an entire row, so the correct syntax is

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE...
```

if you do DELETE (something) FROM will not work

Hope it helps

Comment: That method is correct too. [Check](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) on mysql dev pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM 
  `line`
WHERE
   order_id IN 
      (SELECT id
       FROM order
       WHERE `datetime`< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DELETE FROM `line` WHERE `order_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `order` 
WHERE `datetime` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR));
```

might me heavier.