# Two separate queries instantaneous. Query with a subquery very slow. Why? mysql / mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mariadb

```
DELETE FROM search WHERE sequence_id IN (34546);
```

> Affected rows: 0
>   Time: 0,001s

```
SELECT sequence_id FROM sequences WHERE sequence_status = 1;
```

> OK
>   Time: 0,001s

```
DELETE FROM search WHERE sequence_id IN (SELECT sequence_id FROM sequences WHERE sequence_status = 1);
```

> Affected rows: 0
>   Time: 2,868s

What am i doing wrong?

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM search WHERE sequence_id IN (SELECT sequence_id FROM sequences WHERE sequence_status = 1);
```

[image]

Comment: This is just a theory: Perhaps the subquery needs to be reevaluated for every row in the search table?

Comment: added the "explain" output. Does it fit your theory? How to make it work like this: run a subquery, put whatever it returns in parentheses, run outer query?

Comment: It shouldn't do this. I did find a bug report. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25926 Perhaps you can copy the fast version in your code? Or better, delete by joining tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154707/delete-from-one-table-with-join

Comment: The fast code from the bug report did not change anything. But what a revelation was to me that one can delete from one table only when working on a join (in the second link)!
DELETE search FROM search NATURAL JOIN sequences WHERE sequences.sequence_status = 1;
> Affected rows: 122
> Time: 0,019s

Comment: Good, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a join rather than the `IN`.

```
DELETE search
       FROM search
            INNER JOIN sequences
                       ON sequences.sequence_id = search.sequence_id
       WHERE sequences.sequence_status = 1;
```

To support it, create an index on `search (sequence_id)` and `sequences (sequence_id, sequence_status)`.

```
CREATE INDEX search_sequence_id
             ON search
                (sequence_id);

CREATE INDEX sequences_sequence_id_sequence_status
             ON sequences
                (sequence_id,
                 sequence_status);
```

Comment: You want the query to start with `sequences`, hence you need the composite index `(sequence_status, sequence_id)` in this  order.

Answer (score 0):

- `IN ( SELECT ... )` is notoriously poorly optimized, especially in older versions of MySQL/MariaDB.  Avoid it!
- Complex `DELETE`/`UPDATE` used to have a lame parser/optimizer.  I suspect this is what you hit.  Newer versions unified the code, thereby improving optimization of deletes/updates.
- A time of 1ms often implies that the Query cache took over.  (Hence, I don't trust your first two timings.)
- How big is `sequences`?  Do you have `INDEX(sequence_status, sequence_id)`?
- Give the multi-table `DELETE` syntax a try, it *may* be optimized differently.

Comment: I do not think the issue of query cache kicking in is relevant, i do not mind it in the subquery, which is not the case, apparently. Sequences is a tiny table of 13000 rows, each of 15 int/varchars. sequence_id is primary key. sequence_status is indexed, too. Will try the DELETE with JOIN, thanks.