# Select max version number for each group consisting of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have the following tables:

Apps

```
TYPE_ID | BUILD_ID | CONFIG_ID | VERSION_ID | (All foreign keys to the respective tables)
1       | 1        | 1         | 1          |
1       | 1        | 1         | 2          |
2       | 2        | 3         | 3          |
2       | 2        | 3         | 4          |
```

Versions

```
ID | major | minor | patch
1  | 1     |0      |1
2  | 2     |0      |0
3  | 3     |0      |3
4  | 4     |0      |0
```

I need to select highest version rows from `Apps` table for each unique combinations of `TYPE_ID`, `BUILD_ID` and `CONFIG_ID`.

The version number should be calculated by `MAX(major * 1000000 + minor * 1000 + patch)` in the versions table.

So from the given example of the `Apps` table the result would be:

```
TYPE_ID | BUILD_ID | CONFIG_ID | VERSION_ID |
1       | 1        | 1         | 2          |
2       | 2        | 3         | 4          |
```

Have tried something like this:

```
SELECT p1.* FROM Apps p1 
            INNER JOIN ( 
                SELECT max(VERSION_ID) MaxVersion, CONFIG_ID 
                FROM Apps  
                GROUP BY CONFIG_ID
            ) p2 
            ON p1.CONFIG_ID = p2.CONFIG_ID 
                AND p1.VERSION_ID = p2.MaxVersion  
            GROUP BY `TYPE_ID`, `BUILD_ID`, `CONFIG_ID`
```

But `MAX` is applied on the `VERSION_ID` and I need `MAX` to be applied on `major`, `minor` and `patch` combinations.

**MySQL Version 15.1 distribution 5.5.56-MariaDB**

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: your expected result has version id (or, version number ?)

Comment: does `max(x * y * x ...)` solve the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik see the edit.

Comment: @MariusKurgonas please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332488/2469308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the maximum version per `type_id, build_id, config_id` using the formula described in your question, use it again same formula to locate the version:

```
SELECT sq.type_id, sq.build_id, sq.config_id, versions.id AS version_id_max
FROM (
    SELECT type_id, build_id, config_id, MAX(major * 1000000 + minor * 1000 + patch) AS max_version
    FROM apps
    INNER JOIN versions ON apps.version_id = versions.id
    GROUP BY type_id, build_id, config_id
) sq
INNER JOIN versions ON max_version = major * 1000000 + minor * 1000 + patch
```

```
+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| type_id | build_id | config_id | version_id_max |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|       1 |        1 |         1 |              2 |
|       2 |        2 |         3 |              4 |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Brillian @Salman A, this is almost what i need, but would it be possible to return just an original `VERSION_ID` column at the end instead of the last 5 columns? Cheers!

Comment: @MariusKurgonas just name the columns (I used `*` to show all details including unnecessary ones).

Comment: Cheers! This is what i need - but with the original names of the `Apps` table columns. So if i renamed `version_id_max` to `version_id` that would be it!

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing Nested Derived subqueries, and a [bit of hacky way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314208/2469308) of identifying `VERSION_ID` corresponding to **MAX** `VERSION_NO`.

We basically first get a **derived** table determining the `VERSION_NO` for each row in the `Apps` table.

Now using that derived table as a source for `SELECT`, we group by on the `TYPE_ID`, `BUILD_ID` and `CONFIG_ID`, and using a [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and string manipulation based trick, we determine the `VERSION_ID` corresponding to **maximum** `VERSION_NO`, for a group.

Try the following:

```
SELECT nest.TYPE_ID, 
       nest.BUILD_ID, 
       nest.CONFIG_ID, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nest.VERSION_ID   
                                    ORDER BY nest.VERSION_NO DESC  
                                    SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1) AS VERSION_ID 
FROM (
       SELECT A.TYPE_ID, 
              A.BUILD_ID, 
              A.CONFIG_ID, 
              A.VERSION_ID, 
              (V.major*1000000 + V.minor*1000 + V.patch) AS VERSION_NO 
       FROM Apps AS A
       INNER JOIN Versions AS V ON V.ID = A.VERSION_ID 
     ) AS nest 
GROUP BY nest.TYPE_ID, nest.BUILD_ID, nest.CONFIG_ID
```

### [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb73e4/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select type_id, build_id, config_id,
      max(1000000*v.major+1000*v.minor+v.patch) as version 
from apps a left join versions v on a.version_id=v.id 
group by type_id, build_id, config_id
```

Comment: Cheers! But this does not return the original `Apps` table rows in the end results thus - did not accept this as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a1.type_id, a1.build_id, a1.config_id, a1.version_id
FROM apps a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    (SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM apps a2
    WHERE a2.type_id = a1.type_id
    AND a2.build_id = a1.build_id
    AND a2.config_id = a1.config_id
    AND a2.version_id > a1.version_id))
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe Taras, but it seems that this example compared version id`s and not actual major minor patch versions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, what I do here, I imitate well-known function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type_id, Build_id, Config_id ORDER BY major desc, minor desc, patch desc)`.

```
select @type_id_lag := 0, @build_id_lag :=0, @config_id_lag := 0, @rn := 0;

select type_id, build_id, config_id, major, minor, patch from (
    select case when @type_id_lag = type_id and
                     @build_id_lag = build_id and
                     @config_id_lag = config_id then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn := 1 rn,
           @type_id_lag := type_id type_id,
           @build_id_lag := build_id build_id,
           @config_id_lag := config_id config_id,
           v.major, v.minor, v.patch
    from Apps a
    left join Versions v on a.version_id = v.id
    order by a.type_id, a.build_id, a.config_id,
             v.major desc, v.minor desc, v.patch desc
) a where rn = 1;
```