# Get other columns associated with MAX column

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

BIDS

```
record_id    listing_id  user_id  amount   proxy
------------------------------------------------
43           26          3        75000    0
44           26          29       79100    1
45           26          29       75100    0
```

LISTINGS

```
record_id    reserve_price   start_price   user_id   status
-----------------------------------------------------------
26           80000           75000         2         0
```

I want to return the row associated with the maximum non-proxy bid amount, i.e. where proxy=0

My query is as follows, but it does not return the correct user_id. The maximum non-proxy bid is $75100, but it returns user_id=3, which is incorrect.

```
select 
        IFNULL(MAX(b.amount),0) AS maxBid
        , IFNULL(l.reserve_price,0) as reserve_price
        , IFNULL(l.start_price,0) as start_price
        , b.user_id 
    from bids b 
     join listings l on l.record_id = b.listing_id 
     where b.listing_id = 26 
     and l.status = 0 
     and b.proxy <> 1 
     order by maxBid desc, high_bidder desc limit 1
```

I've looked at other solutions to similar problems, but can't get anything to work so far.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Version 5.7 I think

Comment: @user460114 check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358021/2469308

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL versions < 8.0 (lack of window functions), you can try the following:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(MAX(b.amount),0) AS maxBid
    , IFNULL(l.reserve_price,0) as reserve_price
    , IFNULL(l.start_price,0) as start_price
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.user_id   
                                   ORDER BY b.amount DESC  
                                   SEPARATOR ','), 
                      ',', 
                      1) AS user_id 
FROM bids b 
JOIN listings l on l.record_id = b.listing_id 
WHERE b.listing_id = 26 
 and l.status = 0 
 and b.proxy <> 1 
GROUP BY b.listing_id
```

Interesting use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `GROUP_CONCAT` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313817/select-multiple-field-duplicates-from-mysql-database/52314208#52314208).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to order the results properly. You are not ordering your result by amount. -

```
select 
        IFNULL(MAX(b.amount),0) AS maxBid
        , IFNULL(l.reserve_price,0) as reserve_price
        , IFNULL(l.start_price,0) as start_price
        , b.user_id 
    from bids b 
     join listings l on l.record_id = b.listing_id 
     where b.listing_id = 26 
     and l.status = 0 
     and b.proxy <> 1 
     order by b.amount desc, maxBid desc, high_bidder desc limit 1
```