# Delete rows which contains same data in 3 columns and different data in 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

Delete rows which contains same data in 3 columns and different data in 1 column

I have a table with the columns: c1, c2, c3, c4, modifyday

I would like to delete rows which contains same data in c1, c2, c3 columns and different data in c4 with an earlier modifyday.

I already wrote a query to delete columns which contains same data in columns c1, c2, c3 - but I'm not sure how to check if the data in c4 is different in this query result.

```
delete c1,c2,c3, count( * )
FROM table
GROUP BY c1,c2,c3,
HAVING count( * ) >1
```

Comment: Do you want to delete both/all rows, or do you want to keep one of them?

Comment: i would like to keep the last modify row.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the table with an aggregate query that selects `(c1, c2, c3)` records having more than one distinct `c4` value:

```
delete t
from mytable t
inner join (
    select c1, c2, c3 from mytable group by c1, c2, c3 having count(distinct c4) > 1
) g on g.c1 = t.c1 and g.c2 = t.c2 and g.c3 = t.c3
```

Comment: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 4,Token line offset = 115,Token in error = distinct ]

Comment: @DevApps: this is not a MySQL error message. You should run the query directly against your database to test it.

Answer (score 0):

With a self join:

```
delete t 
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.c1 = t.c1 and tt.c2 = t.c2 and tt.c3 = t.c3 and tt.c4 <> t.c4 
and tt.modifyday > t.modifyday;
```

Comment: `tt.c4 <> t.c4`? I'd guess `tt.c4 < t.c4`, to keep one of the rows. (But I don't know MySQL.)

Comment: There is no requirement to keep 1 of the rows (is there and I missed it?)/

Comment: Well, I just guess OP wants to get rid of too similar rows, i.e. keep one.

Comment: I don't think so. Even the posted attempted code does not indicate anything like that.

Comment: one more detail guys about the table: there is one more column which called "modifyday" and i would like to delete the last modify day.

Comment: Try my edited answer. Change the sign `<` to `>` if you meant the opposite.

Comment: thanks for your answer about this query, forpas.
but i think i missing something in your query... i`m new in mysql..
can you pls specify what do you mean by table name t and table name tt?

Comment: `tablename` is the name of your table. `t` and `tt` are 2 different aliases of this table because the code does a *self join*.

Comment: thanks for your explaination about self-join in mysql.
Should i edit something in your query?
because i tried to execute this query, and there is an error message "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = from ]

Comment: As it is the sql statement  it is syntactically correct. I don't know how you use it. The error message you get is not a direct error message of SQL Server. Probably you run the code modified to suit your needs and maybe through a programming language for which I don't know anything about.

Comment: when i executed the command with select *  (beside delete t) i got all the relevant rows which need to delete. but the delete command didn`t work in this query

Comment: Except the typo `modifydate` instead of `modifyday` which is your column's name, there is no other syntactical error. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bSftbmBqAQLz5nfefTLk7/0 which compiles and runs fine. Also I made an error in my previous comment, this is MySql code and not SQL Server, right?

Comment: i changed the colum name to the correct column name.
yes, it`s mysql.
looks like the issue is about 'delete t' command in this query

Comment: This is exactly the MySql syntax, see also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154876/10498828

Comment: i`m using vs2012 toolbox to execute this command on db... maybe i should use any other tool?

Comment: I don't use this tool so I can't tell. If it is MySql compatible it should work.

Comment: can you pls specify which tool do you use in order to execute mysql commands?

Comment: MySql workbench, but for simple tasks and queries I use fiddles like the link I posted earlier.